# Wordpress Customiser Refresh Issues

Tags: javascript, wordpress

OK, I have been working with the customiser now for a number of days and one issue seems to be persisting, it may be the way I am thinking about this but can not see a solution in the API.

Basically I have a solid working set of controls and panels and have live updates working for things like colour pickers and text updates however I want to use settings like a full width setting for example that allows me to insert a php ternary operator to check if a theme_mod is a certain value and insert some text, php or css to make the change.

Obviously these changes are not being reflected in the preview window as it does not reload the entire page so logical operations are not showing until I have saved and done a manual reload of the page, I know I can not simply reload the iFrame but I am not sure what I can do.

Hopefully I have explained this well enough, many thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I realise that the values may need to be saved in order for them to show in the refresh which is actually fine, I dont mind posting the values back and then reloading. I can handle the reloading part in js by using the .previewer.refresh(); action however I do not know how to post the values or trigger the save action. Any help would be great.